# How to save many print view with the same settings?

Tags: print-composer, zoom, qgis-2.6

I use QGIS 2.6.1 and I need to save more than 100 map shots (one for each Municipality) for future print and I need to save both the print settings and each shots (with positions and zoom levels).

With the print compositions I can save the settings but not the shots, savings the models I have the positions and the zooms but not the settings

Comment: are you using the atlas functionality?

Comment: @iant I did not know atlas, now i'm trying with it it but i can not save the different zoom levels